# App crash in main method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, program-entry-point

I have been getting a rare crash in my app. I am able to track it via hockey app tool integrated with the app. But, unfortunately i am not able to find out any clue about it so as to resolve it.

The crash is happening in the main method of my application in thread 0. I would like to post the stack trace for better analysis. Here it is.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x34ed7f46 _objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                                0x2ac884cf -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 472
2   UIKit                                0x2ac88593 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 52
3   UIKit                                0x2ac7dd21 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2266
4   UIKit                                0x2aa962df -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 184
5   UIKit                                0x2a9c0677 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 512
6   QuartzCore                           0x2a3e8ccd -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 134
7   QuartzCore                           0x2a3e46b5 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 358
8   QuartzCore                           0x2a3e453d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 14
9   QuartzCore                           0x2a3e3f21 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 222
10  QuartzCore                           0x2a3e3d25 CA::Transaction::commit() + 322
11  UIKit                                0x2ac0bc43 _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 208
12  UIKit                                0x2ac0bad5 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsPassingTestForAppResume:] + 14
13  UIKit                                0x2ac2c8f3 -[UIApplication _updateSnapshotAndStateRestorationArchiveForBackgroundEvent:saveState:exitIfCouldNotRestoreState:] + 200
14  UIKit                                0x2ac2bda3 __80-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 112
15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3542b8cb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3542b8b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
17  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3542f0bf __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 723
18  CoreFoundation                       0x274eabe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 6
19  CoreFoundation                       0x274e92e9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1510
20  CoreFoundation                       0x27437621 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
21  CoreFoundation                       0x27437433 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
22  GraphicsServices                     0x2e7bd0a9 _GSEventRunModal + 137
23  UIKit                                0x2aa22359 _UIApplicationMain + 1441
```

The crash being in the main thread, i don't get any clue of where and how to start tracing this crash.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add one all exception breakpoint

Comment: Blind, but educated guess: You return nil in one of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods. Or maybe it is something else, but the problem is most likely located in this method.

Comment: go to xcode and select breakpoints and at the botton of the pane there is a plus button -> select add Exception breakpoint -> it will show the exception.you are doing some reload data kind of call.and it has views and frames are going wrong